# How can I get register information by passing it through props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to convert the input element to a component using React and passing the props through it, to be able to use this component in different places in the app, I'm using react-hook-form, when I tried to pass the register through props I got this error and page doesn't load.

Please find the error logs followed by the code below:
[image: Error Log 1]

[image: Error Log 2]

```
LoginEn.jsx

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import Input from "../input/Input";

function LoginEn({ login, changLang, lang }) {
    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors },
        formState,
        reset,
        trigger,
    } = useForm();

    const onSubmit = (data) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        reset();
    };
    console.log(register());
    return (
        <>
            <section className="login" id="content">
                <div className="login-details">
                    <svg
                        viewBox="0 0 100 100"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1000/svg"
                        fill="#fff"
                        className="svg-left"
                    >
                        <circle cx="-20" cy="-35" r="50" />
                    </svg>
                    <svg
                        viewBox="0 0 100 100"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1000/svg"
                        fill="#fff"
                        className="svg-right"
                    >
                        <circle cx="100" cy="1" r="30" />
                    </svg>
                    <div className="login-header">
                        <h2>Login Page</h2>
                        <span>Designed with Adobe XD</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="login-body">
                        <div className="row justify-content-center">
                            <div className="login-leftSide col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
                                <h3 className="text-start">Logo</h3>
                                <picture>
                                    <img className="img-fluid" src={login} alt="" />
                                </picture>
                            </div>
                            <div className="login-rightSide d-flex flex-column justify-content-center text-start col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
                                <div className="p-3 watch-responsive">
                                    <div>
                                        <div className="d-flex justify-content-between watch-responsive">
                                            <h4 className="d-flex align-items-end">
                                                Welcome Back!
                                            </h4>
                                            <span
                                                className="fw-bold lang"
                                                onClick={changLang}
                                            >
                                                {lang ? "AR" : "EN"}
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                        <h6>Login to continue</h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} method="POST">
                                        <div className="login-inputs d-flex flex-column gap-2 mb-3 ">
                                            <div className="input-field d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                                                <span className="icon-user"></span>
                                     **           <Input
                                                    errors={errors}
                                                    register={register}
                                                    trigger={trigger}
                                                    name="email"
                                                    placeholder="Write your Email"
                                                    pattern={
                                                        /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/i
                                                    }
                                                ></Input>**
                                            </div>
                                            <span className="errorMsg">
                                                {errors.email?.type === "required" &&
                                                    "email is required"}
                                                {errors.email?.type === "pattern" &&
                                                    "Entered a wrong format"}
                                            </span>
  
            </section>
        </>
    );
}

export default LoginEn;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
input.jsx

import React from "react";

const Input = ({ errors, register, trigger, name, placeholder, pattern }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <input
                className={errors.email && "border border-danger"}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                name={name}
                {...register(
                    { name },
                    {
                        required: true,
                        pattern: { pattern },
                    }
                )}
                onKeyUp={() => {
                    trigger({ name });
                }}
            />
        </>
    );
};

export default Input;
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please [avoid uploading images of code/errors/data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13927534) in your question. Instead, use the available SO formatting tools.

Comment: thanks, @MissSkooter for your advice, well noted